# Using Cocoa static library built in c++, some ObjC code tries to rebuilt it in OC

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I am programming in Xcode in ObjC using a Cocoa static library built in c++ (built by me). For the library project, I made one public header(.hpp) that includes all the other header files(.hpp). Then in the ObjC project, I wrote a wrapper code(.hpp and .mm) to play as the interface, so it includes the public hpp header. To access the library, I then include the wrapper code in a normal m file. I believe all of these followed the tutorials, as it worked well for a few weeks.

However, after doing something stupid yesterday, the compiler for the ObjC project started to insist on building all the headers in ObjC. It first had problems with openCV packages in the c++ library, producing errors saying thoses are supposed to be built in c++ (as shown below). Even if I removed the openCV, the compiler cannot find any standard c++ libararies. I tried renaming the .hpp's to .h but it did not work.

Any suggestions on what I did wrong and how I can fix this?Much appreciated!

([image])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your errors are coming from compiling `ImageProcessor.m`. `.m` is the extension Obj-C files, so the compiler will try to compile it, and everything it includes as Obj-C.

I'd suggest renaming it to `ImageProcessor.mm`.

Answer (score 0):

After learning more about header files, I realized what I did wrong: I included every header in the interface, so they are re-built every time outside the library, even if they are referenced by none-c++ code. The solution is to separate the interface header with other headers in the library completely.